# Boolean function compared with true/false

Tags: c++

So I have a boolean function:

```
bool func(int x, int y){
       // do something
   if (x==y){
      return true;
      }  
}
```

When I use the function in an if loop,

```
if (func(x, y)){
   // do something
}
```

it isn't the same thing as

```
if (func(x, y) == true){
   // do something
}
```

What is the reason for this?

BTW: I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks!

Comment: Re: "What is the reason for this?" -- the same reason someone would write `if (((func(x, y) == true) == true)`: they don't know the language well enough to write simple code.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statements are exactly the same thing. They are logically equivalent to each other.

The problem is that your `func` does not return a value if the comparison fails.

This results in undefined behavior.

If your compiler yelled at you, when you tried to compile that, this would be a demonstration of why you should not ignore warning messages from your compiler.

If your compiler was silent, check its documentation how to turn on additional warnings.

Comment: It should not even compile!

Comment: The OP might consider changing `if (x == y) { return true; }` to the more straightforward and correct `return x == y;`. If you can avoid actually typing `true`/`false` and just let your tests do it for you, I find it usually makes for better code.

Comment: @sergiol: It will generally compile, albeit with warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statements are indeed the same, but the problem with your code is that if `x` is not equal to `y`, it can't return anything. And honestly this code shouldn't even compile as VC++ should realize it will not return anything if `x` is not equal to `y`, and this function will not function as intended.  You might want to change your code to this to be more safe:

```
bool func(int x, int y){
       // do something
   return x==y;
}
```

This makes it so that it returns a boolean no matter what. If x equals y return true otherwise return false. Again, this must be a bug with the Visual Studio compiler, or you are not giving us the correct code. FYI: If this were the g++ or clang++ compiler, that code would not have compiled due to the reason I explained.

You should turn on additional warnings for your VC++ compiler by using `-Wall` (all warnings).  This should help you accomplish that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/12/14/off-by-default-compiler-warnings-in-visual-c/

Always make sure you have `-Wall` turned on to have "safe" code, and also be sure your function will return if anything happens unless it's a `void`/no returning function.  This is normally done by a compiler like clang++.  There is a plugin for clang++ and VA: http://llvm.org/builds/. You can also search for clang in your Visual Studio Plugin Manager to install directly from the IDE.

Comment: It will generally compile, albeit with warnings.

Comment: See new answer @ShadowRanger

Comment: It's not a compiler bug; failing to return from a function is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required